# Redirect shouldn't happen

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I have this jquery:

```
$('#SaveButton').click(function () {
    var url = $('#SaveButton').data("url");
    var overview = $('#SaveButton').data("overview");
    var createurl = $('#SaveButton').data("createurl");
    var flag = true;
    var picker = $('#DepositDatePicker').data('datetimepicker');
    var utcDate = getFormattedDate(picker.getLocalDate());
    if (flag) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                DepositTemplateVersionId: $('input#DepositTemplateVersionId').val(),
                depositDate: $('#depositDateValue').val()
            },
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (result) { document.location = overview; },
            error: function (x, t, e) { document.localName = createurl; }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

This is what happens on my controller:

```
public ActionResult SaveDeposit(DepositCreateScreenDTO depositCreateScreenDTO) //int depositTemplateVersionId, DateTime depositDate)
        {
            try
            {
                if (this.ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    CommandsServiceAgent.Call(c => c.CreateDeposit(depositCreateScreenDTO.DepositTemplateVersionId, depositCreateScreenDTO.DepositDate));
                    this.Success("Successfully created deposit");
                    return null;
                }
                else
                {
                    string Message = "";
                    var modelStateErrors = this.ModelState.Keys.SelectMany(key => this.ModelState[key].Errors);
                    foreach (ModelError modelError in modelStateErrors)
                    {
                        Message += modelError.ErrorMessage + System.Environment.NewLine;
                    }

                    Danger(Message);
                    return null;
                }
            }
            catch (FaultException<FaultDTO> ex)
            {
                Danger(string.Format (ex.Message));
                return Json(new { Message = ex.Message });
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Danger("Error creating deposit");
                return null;
            }
        }
```

When everything is going OK, my page gets redirected fine.
When an error happens and my model isn't valid, it should stay on the same page.
For some reason I get redirect to my overview-page.

Comment: The jQuery isn't erroring as the ajax call works fine.

Comment: Returning `null` does not cause the ajax function to fail. You should test the result in the success function - `if(result) {do something } else { null was returned so do something else }`

Comment: Its better to have return type as `JsonResult` instead of `ActionResult` for the action method called through Ajax. So you can simply return the string and validate on your success/fail function of $.ajax method.

Answer (score 0):

The ajax result always call the success function because you are returning null...
To call the error function in ajax statement, your controller method have to throw an exception:

```
if (this.ModelState.IsValid)
    ...
else
    throw new HttpException("Error ....");
```

However, you can handle it in your ajax statement:

```
success: function (result) {
    if (result)
        // error...
    else
        // redirect...
}
```